# How do I format a floating point value so that it never uses exponent notation nor has trailing zeros?

Tags: c++, floating-point, string-formatting, iostream

According to [ios_base manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed), I basically have the choice between `defaultfloat` and `fixed` when formatting floating point numbers without exponent notation (with decimal numbers).

However, I want to choose the [maximum precision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) which would produce *a lot* trailing zeros for `fixed` for many numbers (e.g. `1.`) but avoid ever using the exponent notation. If set to `defaultfloat`, it will look right *most* of the time, unless the value is really really small, yet not `0.`. In that case, the default representation switches to scientific notation on its own, which breaks the receiver of the formatted output (since it has no clue what `2.22045e-16` means.

So, how can I have my pie and eat it, too? That is, **non-exponent notation without unnecessary trailing zeroes**.

---

<sub>*Note: I did not test the effect of the `defaultfloat` flag, since my gcc doesn't seem to implement that flag (yet), but I assume it is the default setting which applies without using any flag. I did check the `fixed` flag, which does behave as expected.*</sub>

Comment: What exactly do you want printed when the output is 2.22045e-16? `0` or `0.00000000000000000222045` [not sure I got the right number of zeros, but pretend that it is...]

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The second.

Comment: And if the value is 16.00001210121019, you want exaxctly that, but if the value is 16.5, you want that, am I right? I think you're best off writing your own "float to string". It's not terribly hard.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Yes, you're right. However, regarding writing my own "float to string" ... I hate reinventing the wheel. In particular here, as I think this should be the default case for floating point formatting.

Comment: Well, as you have noticed. I'm working on an answer, but it may take a few minutes, as I will probably at least run some simple stuff through it...

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I suppose one could simply use the fixed with maximum precision and then remove the trailing zeroes, then put all in a nice wrapper. I was mostly hoping I overlooked something, which allows this directly.

Comment: See my answer below, that's roughly what it does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be a proper way to do this with the stdlib, here's my wrapper.

```
  template <typename T>
  struct FpFormat {
    template <typename Stream>
    static Stream& setfmt(Stream& str) {
      return str;
    }
    template <typename String>
    static String const& untrail(String const& str) {
      return str;
    }
  };
  template <typename T>
  struct FpFormatFloats {
    template <typename Stream>
    static auto setfmt(Stream& str) -> decltype(str << std::fixed << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10)) {
      return str << std::fixed << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10);
    }
    template <typename String>
    static String untrail(String str) {
      if (str.find('.') == String::npos)
        return str;
      return ([](String s){
        return String(s.begin(),s.begin()+((s.back() == '.')?(s.size()-1):s.size()));
      })(str.substr(0,(str+"0").find_last_not_of('0')+1));
    }
  };
  template <> struct FpFormat<float> : FpFormatFloats<float> {};
  template <> struct FpFormat<double> : FpFormatFloats<double> {};
  template <> struct FpFormat<long double> : FpFormatFloats<long double> {};

  template <typename T>
  std::string toString(T x) {
    std::stringstream str;
    FpFormat<T>::setfmt(str) << x;
    return FpFormat<T>::untrail(str.str());
  }
```

Comment: Sadly, this hardcodes `.` (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b72ae760073d8832)

Comment: I realize you accepted your own answer so this code works for you but it doesn't actually fulfill the "never uses exponent notation" requirement (try very large or very small numbers). Mats' answer is closer to hitting that nail. I'm just writing this comment to inform others who need the no-exponent feature.

Comment: I think you should use `max_digits10` not `digits10`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple method would be something like this:

```
std::string float2string(double f)
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(122) << f;   // 122 is LARGE, but you may find that really tiny or really large numbers still don't work out... 

    std::string s = ss.str();

    std::string::size_type len = s.length();

    int zeros = 0;
    while(len > 1 && s[--len] == '0')
        zeros++;
    if (s[len] == '.')  // remove final '.' if number ends with '.'
        zeros++;
    s.resize(s.length()-zeros);


    return s;
}
```

I have given it some testing. The biggest problem is that it gives a huge number of decimals for some numbers, and things like 0.05 comes out as `0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125`
and 0.7 becomes:
`0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125`

That's because it's not an "exact" number in binary form.

I think the solution is to calculate roughly how many digits you want in the result, by taking the number of integer digits (or floor(log(f)/log(10)+1)) and then subtracting that number from a constant, such as 17, which is the number of digits you can expect from a double. Then remove surplus zeros.

I'll leave that for the moment, as I've got some other stuff to do that I should have started on a little while ago... ;)

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the effort, but [my version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14966914/430766) seems to deal with such numbers properly.

Comment: Sadly, this hardcodes `.` (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b72ae760073d8832)

Comment: In case you don't want to hard-code the maximum exponent `std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<FloatType>::max_exponent)`

Comment: That should be `numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10`, not `max_exponent`. See the example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10).

Comment: Actually neither of those are correct because `setprecision()` wants the number of digits after the decimal point, and `max_digits10` is the number of significant digits. `max_exponent` is just wrong though. The correct number should be something like `max_exponent10 + max_digits10` (probably +1 or 2) which is over 300 so this is not a good general solution...

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it seems like there is no code to do this in either `iostream` or `printf()`. Any by "this" I mean:

1. Print in fixed format.
2. Print the *minimum* number of digits so that the encoding is lossless (i.e. the closest valid floating point number is the one that you printed).

You *can't* just print with a very large precision and strip trailing zeros because there might be non-zero digits that are unnecessary.

I believe the only good way to really do this would be to use dedicated code like [Ryu](https://github.com/ulfjack/ryu).

Another way would be to print the next and previous numbers with very large precision and take the digits after the decimal point that are the same (plus one). It's going to be ugly though.

Answer (score -1):

There's no built-in formatting that will do this for you. You can either produce your own formatter from scratch or you could write one that post-processes the string to remove unnecessary trailing zeros.

For example you could do it using regex substitution:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>

// not thoroughly tested
std::string format(double d, int precision = 100) {
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision);
   ss << d;

   return std::regex_replace(
       std::regex_replace(ss.str(), std::regex(R"((-?\d*\.\d*?)0*$)"), "$1"),
       std::regex(R"(\.$)"), "");
}

int main() {
   std::cout << format(-1) << '\n';
   std::cout << format(1e20) << '\n';
   std::cout << format(1e-20) << '\n';
   std::cout << format(2.22045e-16) << '\n';
}
```

Though using a regex is probably not a particularly efficient solution.

Comment: Sadly, this hardcodes `.` (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b72ae760073d8832)