# How to produce formatting similar to .NET's '0.###%' in iostreams?

Tags: c++, iostream

I would like to output a floating-point number as a percentage, with *up to* three decimal places.

I know that iostreams have three different ways of presenting floats:

- "default", which displays using either the rules of `fixed` or `scientific`, depending on the number of significant digits desired as defined by `setprecision`;
- `fixed`, which displays a fixed number of decimal places defined by `setprecision`; and
- `scientific`, which displays a fixed number of decimal places but using scientific notation, i.e. mantissa + exponent of the radix.

These three modes can be [seen in effect](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7864088f0d5e9fe) with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double d = 0.00000095;
    double e = 0.95;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(3);
    std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::floatfield);
    std::cout << "d = " << (100. * d) << "%\n";
    std::cout << "e = " << (100. * e) << "%\n";
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << "d = " << (100. * d) << "%\n";
    std::cout << "e = " << (100. * e) << "%\n";
    std::cout << std::scientific;
    std::cout << "d = " << (100. * d) << "%\n";
    std::cout << "e = " << (100. * e) << "%\n";
}

// output:
// d = 9.5e-05%
// e = 95%
// d = 0.000%
// e = 95.000%
// d = 9.500e-05%
// e = 9.500e+01%
```

None of these options satisfies me.

I would like to avoid any scientific notation here as it makes the percentages really hard to read. I want to keep at most three decimal places, and it's ok if very small values show up as zero. However, I would also like to avoid trailing zeros in fractional places for cases like 0.95 above: I want that to display as in the second line, as "95%".

In .NET, I can achieve this with a custom format string like "0.###%", which gives me a number formatted as a percentage with at least one digit left of the decimal separator, and *up to* three digits right of the decimal separator, trailing zeros skipped: http://ideone.com/uV3nDi

Can I achieve this with iostreams, without writing my own formatting logic (e.g. special casing small numbers)?

Comment: `if number is smaller than 0.01 use method B else use method A`. Or just calculate those (up to) 6 characters by hand. Posting for completeness.

Comment: (Btw, for this exercise I am willing to accept manually adding the percent sign. However, for completeness: http://ideone.com/sCPnmr)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format a floating point value so that it never uses exponent notation nor has trailing zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965902/how-do-i-format-a-floating-point-value-so-that-it-never-uses-exponent-notation-n)

Answer (score 4):

I'm reasonably certain nothing built into iostreams supports this directly.

I think the cleanest way to handle it is to round the number before passing it to an iostream to be printed out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

double rounded(double in, int places) {
    double factor = std::pow(10, places);

    return std::round(in * factor) / factor;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> values{ 0.000000095123, 0.0095123, 0.95, 0.95123 };

    for (auto i : values)
        std::cout << "value = " << 100. * rounded(i, 5) << "%\n";
}
```

Due to the way it does rounding, this has a limitation on the magnitude of numbers it can work with. For percentages this probably isn't an issue, but *if* you were working with a number close to the largest that can be represented in the type in question (`double` in this case) the multiplication by `pow(10, places)` could/would overflow and produce bad results.

Though I can't be *absolutely* certain, it doesn't seem like this would be likely to cause an issue for the problem you seem to be trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

#### This solution is terrible.

I am serious. I don't like it. It's probably slow and the function has a stupid name. Maybe you can use it for test verification, though, because it's so dumb I guess you can easily see it pretty much has to work.

It also assumes decimal separator to be `'.'`, which doesn't have to be the case. The proper point could be obtained by:

```
char point = std::use_facet< std::numpunct<char> >(std::cout.getloc()).decimal_point();
```

But that's still not solving the problem, because the characters used for digits could be different and in general this isn't something that should be written in such a way.

#### Here it is.

```
template<typename Floating>
std::string formatFloatingUpToN(unsigned n, Floating f) {
    std::stringstream out;
    out << std::setprecision(n) << std::fixed;
    out << f;
    
    std::string ret = out.str();
    
    // if this clause holds, it's all zeroes
    if (std::abs(f) < std::pow(0.1, n))
        return ret;
    
    while (true) {
        if (ret.back() == '0') {
            ret.pop_back();
            continue;
        } else if (ret.back() == '.') {
            ret.pop_back();
            break;
        } else
            break;
    }
        
    return ret;
}
```

And [**here it is in action**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/562fa457fb40b497).

Comment: So basically you cannot achieve this with the STL. But a nice encapsulated solution works - as always, even if the implementation is terrible.